# Im struggling to see how these are presynaptic terminals/knobs and not post synaptic

Tags: neuroscience, physiology, central-nervous-system, synapses, cranial-nerves

[image]

How are these presynaptic terminals ? The action potential is generated at the axon hillock and moves down the axon (in this case to the right) , then at the end of the axon should be axon terminals and presynaptic knobs. Shouldn't the dendrites shown here have post synaptic knobs with receptors for the neurotransmitters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fibers in green are axons and axon terminals **from other neurons**, not the one colored orange.

Yes, there would be post-synaptic structures associated with these but those are not drawn in this cartoon.

Answer (score 1):

The green ones you see are the synaptic knobs or presynaptic terminals of other neurons of which some lie on the surface of dendrite of the given neuron(Axodendritic) and some on the soma of the neuron(Axosomatic). Also please note that the synaptic knobs(green) on soma is not peircing it rather imagine it in 3d, where the synaptic knobs are coming from top, outside your book to the neuron making a synapse.